# how to confirm the user name else allowed to enter a custom user name

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

so I have a script that you enter in the first name middle initial and last name and from that the logon name is created but there might be times where that is being use and will need to enter in a custom user name how can I do this? the logonname does show how i want it but the if statement doesn't let me change it when I press C or c

any help thanks in advance

```
#getting user information
Write-Host "Gathering information for new account creation."
Write-Host
$firstname = Read-Host "Enter in the First Name"
Write-Host
$middlename = Read-Host "Enter in Middle Initial"
Write-Host
$lastname = Read-Host "Enter in the Last Name"
Write-Host
$fullname = "$firstname $lastname"
#getting samaccountname with first letter of first name, first letter of middle name, first 4 letters 
of last name
$i = 1
$p = 4
$logonname = $firstname.substring(0,$i).tolower() + $middlename.Substring(0,$i).tolower() + 
$lastname.Substring(0,$p).tolower()



$confirm = Read-Host "Is [$logonname] correct  or would you like to change it (Y/C)"
  if ($confirm -eq "y" -or "Y"){
#proceed

     } else { write-host 
     $logonname = Read-Host "Enter Custom User Name"
 }
```

Comment: use ANR [Ambiguous Name Resolution, i think] to grab all the names that are similar, find the one with the highest number, increment that number, and finally use that to make your new name.

Comment: ditto to @Lee_Dailey. Apart from that, you need to check if the user actually entered something and that it is not just whitespace. If someone for instance enters nothing in one of the `Read-Host`prompts, your script will error out. If a user is entered with a lastname shorter than 4 characters (it so happens mine is..), your script will error out.. If a user enters whitespaces, you might end up with bad logon names. In short, you need to think this over and add checks on every user input.

Comment: yes i understand that, that is why i am asking them to confirm the name and if not then for them to enter a custom logon name

Answer (score 1):

ok so i was able to get it to work by does this

```
#getting user information
Write-Host "Gathering information for new account creation."
Write-Host
$firstname = Read-Host "Enter in the First Name"
Write-Host
$middlename = Read-Host "Enter in Middle Initial"
Write-Host
$lastname = Read-Host "Enter in the Last Name"   
Write-Host
$fullname = "$firstname $lastname"
#getting samaccountname with first letter of first name, first letter of middle name, 
first 4 letters of last name
$i = 1
$p = 4
$logonname = $firstname.substring(0,$i).tolower() + 
$middlename.Substring(0,$i).tolower() + $lastname.Substring(0,$p).tolower()

Do{
Write-Host
$confirm = Read-Host "Is [$logonname] correct  or would you like to change it (Y/C)"
  if ($confirm -ne "y" -or $confirm -ne "Y"){
       #proceed

     } else {
     }
     if($confirm -eq "y" -or $confirm -eq "Y"){
     }else { $logonname = Read-Host "Enter custom logon name"
     }

   Write-Host
   $confirm = Read-Host "Please confirm [$logonname] is correct (Y or N)"
   if ($confirm -ne "y" -or $confirm -ne "Y"){
     #proceed
   }
     } 
        until ($confirm -eq "y" -or $confirm -eq "Y")     

        Write-Host $logonname
```